# Trimming Image Borders using ImageMagick.Net Produces thin border in Trimmed Image

Tags: c#, imagemagick, system.drawing, imagemagick.net

I'm trimming the extra green borders space around the following image

[image]

But after trimming i get small white borders around the image using Image Magick.net

```
var mfactory = new MagickFactory();
            Bitmap bit;
            using (var image = new MagickImage(mfactory.Image.Create(bmp)))
            {
                // Trimming WhiteSpace
                image.Trim();
                bit = image.ToBitmap();
            }
```

Image with green borders

[image]

Comment: Do you get white or green borders? If green, then you need to add some fuzz value to the trim so that it removes antialiased orange-green mix. If white, then that is likely an illusion or an artifact of the viewing software.  Please show the exact result.

Comment: @fmw42 The exact result is the second image,you can see a green border.

Comment: Add some fuzz value to make the trim remove a mix of orange and green which is what you see that is left from anti-aliasing when drawing the colors. I do not know your API so cannot tell you the exact command.

Comment: @fmw42 Adding fuzz fixed the issue.Thanks